# emulator screen is showing old data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I updated the code of MainPage.xaml, but it still keeps showing me the old code display. In my new code, I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30">

        <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="700" 

       x:Name="MyMap" 

       IsShowingUser="True" 

       MapType="Street" 

       />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

In the old code, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</ContentPage>
```

I removed the label that says Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" and put my Maps:map code there. When I run the application, I get the message saying unfortunately the api demos stopped and then I see the below image. My application is called app1:

[image]

When I click on app1, I get the below screen that shows the old label:

[image]

I am not sure if message "unfortunately the api demos has stopped" has to do anything with this.

My code behind for MainPage.xaml.cs file is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyMap.MoveToRegion(

           MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(

           new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
        }


    }
}
```

Sometimes, I get this message saying there are deployment errors. Below is the message for this:

```
Unexpected install output:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.co.App1-Signed.apk
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A\_work\61\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 337
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\61\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 746
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>
```

I manually removed the app1 from emulator. removed my obj and bin file. Did the clean build and my configuration is pointing to debug. Now I am getting below errors:

```
2>Unexpected install output:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.co.App1-Signed.apk
2>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
2>
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>
```

Below is my androidmanifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.co.App1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="testName">
        <meta-data android:label="com.google.android.maps.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDxhj-n96-YaWHibZU2e5BK02U9UzRCnC0" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And below is the androidManifest properties file

[image]

Below the properties specifications:

```
Install Location: Prefer Internal
Version Number:  1
Version Name : 1.0
Minimum Android Version:  Android 5.0 (API Level 21-Lollipop)
Target Android Version:
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I really need help with this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Perform a clean all / build all on your project and run a debugging session again 2) Manually remove the app from the device/emulator. 3) Make sure your Android SDK is up to date (build tools, emulator, etc...)

Comment: In addition to @SushiHangover's comment - you may want to check that  Solution Configuration is set to `Debug` (Your deployment error suggests it may not be) - and also, right click on `App1.Android > Open Folder in File Explorer` in  in your solution explorer, and deleting the `.bin` and `.obj` files here, before attempting a clean and rebuild

Comment: I manually removed the app. Now I am getting deployment errors. I posted the errors in my original post along with my manifest file

Comment: About deployment errors, I suggest you delete your Android SDK, and reinstall them.